# Hide Magento 2 custom Product Tab from guest customers

Tags: php, magento2

I created a Magento 2 module that creates a custom tab on the product page. How can I hide the content of this tab from guest customer and display a message? Thank you

Comment: Does your module have a controller, or just templates? If you post the code that is relevant we can improve it.

Comment: Just templates. It's getting information from 2 product attributes I created. Anyway it works the way I want to I can't find a way to show it just for logged in customers and maybe just show a message for guest customers. I would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways in the templates, with objectmanager directly or with a preference for the block that renders the template:

In your module file etc/di.xml add a preference for the block that renders the template. 
I think it is `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` but not sure 100%.

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
            type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Then make file Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
     public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
     {
         return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
     }
}
```

And in the template file use the function to check if logged in and do different stuff.

```
if ($block->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
    // Customer is logged in
} else {
    // Customer is not logged in
}
```

OR use objectmanager inside the template file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // Customer is logged in
} else {
   // Customer is not logged in
}
```

EDIT:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $customerSession->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

    if($isLoggedIn){
        // Logged In
    }else{
        // Not Logged In
    }
```

Objectmanager is easy but it is not using dependency injection, which makes magento2 so nice. (I think that is what the reason is)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. The objectmanager seems more suitable for what I'm trying to do. The only problem is that is shows the "else" message both when a customer is logged on or off. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $product = $block->getProduct();
    echo $product->getData('faq');
} else {
// Customer is not logged in
    echo "You need to be logged in!";
}

Comment: maybe like this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91898/71445 , but  I will look into it, I put the code n edited answer